# import from excel to sql server: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to import data from excel to sql server, but I got error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

op: windows 10 64 bit
excel: 32 bit

There is no problem with older excel format xls, problem occurs with xlsx format. 
Is there any esay way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install the following file from microsoft to fix this issue

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Seems that this is not working anymore at least for me, still the same error after installation.

Comment: 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: I have op system: windows 10 64 bit, excel 32 bit

I installed 64 bit version, also tried 32 bit version, but wasnt able to install it.